# What is CTL Model Checking?

Tags: theory, economics, model-checking, ctl

I got asked to write my master thesis on CTL model checking, indeed I am unsure which company might need skills on that topic. Can anyone please tell me for what CTL model checking can be used in future and/or in economy?

And what CTL Model Checking indeed is? As far as I understood it is a mechanism that specifies corectness of a property.

Answer (score 0):

Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking

And rest assured model checking is heavily used in the industry, especially in the hardware community. (i.e., those companies that produce computer hardware, be it CPUs, GPUs, FPGAs, or any other kind of device.)

Stack-overflow works the best if you ask specific questions. Try to formulate something more specific, instead of "opinion" based questions; and you'll get better responses.